# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..2, inclusive: 3

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-sliver

I am getting a flutter Range error despite putting a **child count** on the widget.
This is the initial call for getting the elements from the logic.

The logic works fine and it maps properly but it's showing a range error despite all the length's being finite. It works fine if I put it in a list view but I need the entire screen scrollable hence the need for a sliver List builder

Comment: Can we see the content of your `MenuList` manager/bloc?

Comment: I added it. Can you please help me work it out. The backend is fine and I have no problem mapping it. Still it's not displaying

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
if (res == null) {
       return;
 }
```

to

```
 if (res == null) {
    // return empty list not null ( since null has no lenght) 
   return <MenuItem>[];
 }
```

Comment: I found the solution. The number of items in menuCat and menuData is different. So according to the Sliver builder since the headings have a length of 4 and the count is 28 hence the issue. All I had to do was put menuCat.length in the child count

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that among the two different lengths in StickyHeader, we must pick the one less in number i.e. the menuCat.length(Header length) in the child count.